# Blazor & Custom Certificates

Tags: https, certificate, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm investigating the idea of using Blazor WASM to build a retail application that would run on an office Intranet. The application would be installed on a given machine, to be accessed via browser from any of several machines on the LAN.

The biggest stumbling block I'm running into is the question of how to go about securing the channel.

The app itself would run as a Windows Service, listening on port 443 on one of the workstations, e.g. https://reception/. But how do we tell Blazor to use a self-signed TLS cert for that hostname?

If there's a better way to go about this, I'm all ears. I can't use Let's Encrypt certs, because neither the application nor its hostname will be exposed to the public Internet.

There is a glut of information on working with Blazor to build such an app, but most if not all demos run on localhost. That works fine for dev, but not for production (in a self-hosting scenario, anyway). There doesn't seem to be much discussion at all of this aspect of things.

How can we use a custom certificate for browser requests from the client to a Blazor WASM app?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working using some slightly modified sample code from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#sni-with-servercertificateselector):

```cs
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
  serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
  {
    listenOptions.UseHttps(httpsOptions =>
    {
      var testCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
          "test", "My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
          allowInvalid: true);

      var certs = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2>(
          StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      {
        ["test"] = testCert
      };

      httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
      {
        if (name is not null && certs.TryGetValue(name, out var cert))
        {
          return cert;
        }

        return testCert;
      };
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle SSL is to use IIS that will act as a proxy for your Blazor app.

IIS will give you easy access to well documented SSL settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#standalone-deployment

Comment: Unfortunately, this app's users will not possess the expertise to install/manage IIS and certificates. So this option is not available to me.

Comment: For example, note this statement from the second comment [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/103524): "It is wasted breath to try and talk them through the process." This exactly describes the situation in my case as well.

Comment: Pardon me... I didn't clarify that this will be a retail application, not a one-off where I would have control of such things as IIS, SQL, etc. I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Did you find this ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Good find, I think I'll be able to make use of that.