# How to read client certificate data from blazor web assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly, x509, client-certificates

I am creating an ASP.Net Core 6 Blazor Web Assembly application that runs in an internal network. Users have already been authenticated before arriving at my application. I need to read the information from their X509 client certificate.

In a server application I could do this using HTTPContext. However, HTTPContext does not exist in a Web Assembly and  I haven't yet been able to find an alternate way to do this yet.

How is this done in Blazor Web Assembly (WASM)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285229/in-a-blazor-app-is-it-possible-to-get-the-requested-path-if-the-render-mode-is/60289289#60289289  this case may help,although i don't know how your read the information form certificate

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that answer is about authorization on a Blazor Server application and not about reading a X509 client certificate in a Blazor Web Assembly.

Answer (score 1):

In a Blazor WebAssembly (WASM) application, you cannot directly access the client certificate as you would do in a server application using HttpContext. However, you can set up a secure communication channel between your Blazor WASM application and a Blazor server.

Here is some that may help you set up that communication channel: [Blazor & Custom Certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074456/blazor-custom-certificates)